Can't view SD card used as internal storage
OK, I probably screwed myself here but here's hoping:
I was using an SD card as portable storage until I got fed up of my internal storage constantly filling up thanks to a game getting updates every so often, and having to sacrifice apps to make space for them. Since I would practically never use the SD card for anything else, I decided to back up my stuff and format the SD as internal storage.
Now, when I was prompted to migrate some internal storage to SD card, I dismissed it thinking I could do it later. But then I found that while I'm able to move some apps to the SD card (unfortunately not the one I even wanted to, but whatever), I can't even access the /sdcard portion.
This is what I see in Settings > Storage: 
If I click the SD card it just goes back to the main Settings menu. No file manager apps can see it, but I can still run the two apps. I might have this totally wrong but shouldn't you still be able to see the SD card at least as a portion of the internal storage?
Also, maybe icing on the cake, but I physically ejected the SD card (nothing was running at the time) to put the SIM in my phone, after I moved the apps. All I saw was the icons go grey / inaccessible until I put the tray back in, then they worked fine.
Any pointers please? Thanks

To my knowledge, once you have started using it as internal storage, you cannot access it separately.  You must move apps to it one at a time.   Not all apps are movable to it.
From experiences by  others on this site, most people regret doing this.  If your SD card goes faulty then there is no easy way to recover your apps or their data.

Yeah, does seem that way. I just rolled back to using portable storage and bought a new SD card anyway - the old one still works anyway
